# Stacks and Queues are shown as empty in the debugger. Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, clion, lldb

[image: Screenshot of debugger showing that the queue is empty]

When I debug the program by stopping at a breakpoint, the queues and stacks show as size=0 when they are not, but the other variables like vectors work fine.

MacOS 10.14.1 Mojave Cmake 3.12.3 Xcode C++ compiler LLDB 6.0 Debug Mode

Comment: Question is: How would the debugger calculate the size? Both `std::queue` and `std::stack` are templates accepting another container as template parameter. Maybe the debugger does not get along with this constellation. You might try to dig a little deeper, inspecting the single members of the inner `std::deque` (default container, if none provided). More important than what the debugger shows is how the container behaves anyway. Try assigning `st.size()` to some variable to see...

Comment: Interesting question.  In the future, please post your source code, rather than relying on an image.  This allows others to copy and paste your code into their IDE.

Comment: I see that you are running on Mac OS X.  I get the same output as you using Mac OS X and CLion.  I suspect that your environment is using XCode and CLang.  Could you try this with CLion on Linux using a true gcc/gdb setup.  I hope this is more an issue with the compiler and the debugger than CLion itself.  The debugger for CLang may dump the object differently than gdb would.  As @Aconcagua stated, assigning `st.size()` correctly displays the size of the queue.

Comment: This bug also occurs in Xcode+lldb, no CLion/Jetbrains reqd :( So still no fix :(

Answer (score 4):

The bug is CPP-14918.
The workaround is really simple, which is a good thing!

You must find your active CLion application (this can be in various places.
For instance mine is in my Library at 
~/Library/Application\ Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/191.7141.37/CLion.app

From terminal, cd to the CLion.app directory..
and then cd to 'Contents/bin/lldb/renderers/lldb_formatters'

In there is the file **init**.py
You need to edit that (use sublime, vim, vi, or whatever), and comment out everything except for the import lldb on the first line.

so..

```
import lldb

#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('script import lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.StdDequeSynthProvider -x "^std::deque<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^std::deque<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.StdDeque11SynthProvider -x "^(std::__1::)deque<.+>$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^(std::__1::)deque<.+>$"')
#
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.StdHashtableSynthProvider -x "^(std::tr1::)unordered_set<.+>.*"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^(std::tr1::)unordered_set<.+>.*"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.StdHashtableSynthProvider -x "^(std::tr1::)unordered_map<.+>.*"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^(std::tr1::)unordered_map<.+>.*"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb.formatters.cpp.gnu_libstdcpp.StdMapSynthProvider -x "^std::multimap<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^std::multimap<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.StdSetSynthProvider -x "^std::set<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^std::set<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.StdSetSynthProvider -x "^std::multiset<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^std::multiset<.+> >(( )?&)?$"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.libcxx_hash_table_SynthProvider -x "^(std::__1::)unordered_(multi)?(map|set)<.+> >$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^(std::__1::)unordered_(multi)?(map|set)<.+>.*"')
#
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type synthetic add -l lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.stdmap_SynthProvider -x "^(std::__1::)(multi)?(map|set)<.+> >$"')
#lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -F lldb_formatters.jetbrains_stl_formatters.SizeSummaryProvider -e -x "^(std::__1::)(multi)?(map|set)<.+> >$"')
```

Needless to say, if you don't like the lack of the jetbrains stl formatters then you can uncomment the lines.  However, the problem is in those formatters.

You may not get what you want - there are clearly other problems with the formatters - but you will get eg. the size showing.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a solution for 3 days, and finally I find it. Thank you.

Comment: This bug also occurs in Xcode+lldb, no CLion/Jetbrains reqd :( So still no fix there :(